# Developing App for iXpand Flash Drive required MFI Program?

Tags: ios, usb, mfi

I am looking to develop my IOS application to communicate with [**iXpand Flash Drive**](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HNTY2ZM/A/sandisk-128gb-ixpand-flash-drive-go) using lighting port. I am going to use [iXpand SDK](https://developer.sandisk.com/content/dam/developer-portal/external/sdk/Sandisk_IXpand_SDK-Developer_Guide.pdf) for that. The flash drive is defined in [public database](https://mfi.apple.com/account/accessory-search) of apple. Does this need me to have **MFI Program** to deploy the app on App Store?

Comment: You would not need to join the mfi program because you are not the hardware developer or manufacturer. At most you would need Sandisk to authorise your app to use their hardware, however they do not mention this in their SDK. Why not get a device and see if you can access it from your app?

Comment: We can able to access it from SDK, not sure it will require at the time of deployment on app store.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer it well as I have deal with the same case:

- You need not to have MFI License, as you are not manufacturer of
  iXpand Flash Drive Hardware.
- The SDK does not communicate with WesternDigital to get any information.
- In my case, Apple Does not have asked for MFI details for iXpand. You may just need to provide details harware details for using lighting port.

At last but not least, we cannot 100% sure about apple review process. They can accept / reject with any reason but here you have good chances to accept it if you have valid reason to us external hardware.